# Auto Populate a table with data from a different table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with 2 columns. Column 1 is a name and column 2 is whether or not they have confirmed, I simply use "Yes" to indicate confirmed. I would like to have another table automatically populate with a name when that person calls and confirms. This new table needs to automatically update whenever I update table 1 with "Yes" in the confirmed column. It's also important to note that this will be done on the Microsoft Teams version of Excel as this is a shared schedule that multiple people reference daily.

Comment: If in excel to show a table (possibly in a new tab) of only Yes, then you should be able to use the `FILTER()`, But why not just filter the existing table?

Comment: The first table is used to keep track of people interested in taking a class. As people confirm we want to able to have a separate table of only confirmed individuals because from there I use data validation to make a drop down box on a different sheet of only confirmed individuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @gns100, use the FILTER function to return confirmed names and values.

```
=FILTER(Table1,Table1[Confirmed]="Yes")
```

[image]]

To return only the names, you can use the formula above in combination with the INDEX function.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Confirmed]="Yes"),,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this worked, even for a newbie excel user I was able to implement this.

Comment: Trying to do this with multiple tables on the same sheet results in a "SPILL" error. In this instance I have replaced "table1" with "Table2". I tried replacing the 1 at the end as well but still getting the "SPILL" error in the destination cell.

Comment: @AdamRadwan Spill error means that the result can't be displayed because there are rows and/or columns (where the result will be displayed) that already contain values. You should try to output your result where there are blank rows and/or columns.

Comment: In this instance I have the data from Table1 reporting in A36 through A70. I then built Table2 and have that data reporting to D36 though D70. Is this causing the problem?

Comment: @AdamRadwan Dynamic arrays are not compatible with tables (as you have inserted it inside table 2 - I am assuming that you have formatted D36 to D70 as table). You need to put the formula outside of the table (or delete te table).

Comment: Thank you this was indeed the issue.